# Sum/Product of two periodic functions.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are two periodic functions with period $P$ and $Q$. Now, if there exists any common multiple of P and Q, is it necessary that $F(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ or $G(x) = f(x)g(x)$ are periodic? 
(Here $x$ lies in the domain of $f$, $g$ and $G$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be the common multiple.

Then perforce

$$f(x+R)+g(x+R)=f(x)+g(x)$$
and
$$f(x+R)\cdot g(x+R)=f(x)\cdot g(x).$$

This doesn't mean that the period of the sum or the product is $R$, it could be smaller (e.g. $\cos x\cdot\cos x$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $$R=lcm(P,Q)$$e.g. $lcm(4\pi,6\pi)=12\pi$. Then what will be $$f(x+R)\\g(x+R)$$?

**Edit**

The $lcm$ of two positive real numbers $x$ and $y$ is defined as$$lcm(x,y)=\min \left\{z\in\Bbb R \ \Bigg| \ {z\over x},{z\over y}\in \Bbb N\right\}$$if it exists. The definition above, can be generalized to all non-zero real numbers.

Comment: It does not exist since $\pi\over e$ is not quotient (of course probably, you touched an open problem in math!). You may find a more general form of what you asked in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics under the branch "Analysis".

Comment: What I'm asking is, what is the common multiple of two real numbers? I know if their ratio is rational, then you can work something out. I just think you should have mentioned that.

Comment: You are right. I added more details.